# Why is this PowerShell bit manipulation producing different output than Python?

Tags: powershell, bit-manipulation, powershell-2.0, bit, twos-complement

I have a script in Python and PowerShell intending to do the same thing. When I do a "not" operator, and then `-1 % 256` operation in both scripts, I get different output:

**PowerShell**

```
-bnot 0: -1
(-1 % 256): -1
```

**Python**

```
(~0): -1
(-1 % 256): 255
```

And, on a different system, I get different output again from PowerShell:

**PowerShell**

```
-bnot 0:  18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615 % 256: 255
```

**Python**

```
-bnot 0: -1
(-1 % 256): 255
```

How can I get my PowerShell `-bnot` and `%` operators to produce the same output as the Python script every time? The PowerShell versions are the same.

Comment: Force the type of number explicitly? In the second example, you're getting an unsigned integer.

Comment: Do you know what Python is using? And how I would force that in PowerShell?

Comment: I don't have a windows around, but I guess something like `-bnot [int]0` should do.

Comment: No, I don't think that's working.

Comment: Actually PowerShell v2.0 or newer? What OS, which PowerShell host (console or ISE or other?) What Python version? PowerShell with no profile? What's different about the two systems? Are you actually doing the tests as shown, or are you using variables? if so, `$x.GetType()` in PowerShell and `type(x)` in Python, what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the correct answer was that PowerShell does not handle modulus with negative numbers as in other languages.

[How to get PowerShell to perform modulus on negative numbers correctly.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/6d23ad7e-61a4-45e7-bf6d-2418cfdbe7fe/how-to-get-powershell-to-perform-modulus-on-negative-numbers-correctly?forum=ITCG)

Answer (score 1):

The first example is explained by the fact that in PowerShell (like most other language implementation on .NET) `%` is a *remainder* operator, not a *modulus* operator. Eric Lippert [explains the difference in this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/12/05/whats-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus/).

In the second example, you seem to apply the binary NOT operator to an unsigned 64-bit integer. An unsigned integer obviously cannot be negative anything, so what you see is correctly the integer representation of applying NOT to `0x0`:

```
PS C:\> -bnot [int]0
-1
PS C:\> -bnot [uint64]0
18446744073709551615

PS C:\> ([int]0).ToString('X2').PadLeft(8,'0')
00000000
PS C:\> ([int]-1).ToString('X2').PadLeft(8,'0')
FFFFFFFF
PS C:\> ([uint64]0).ToString('X2').PadLeft(16,'0')
0000000000000000
PS C:\> ([uint64]18446744073709551615).ToString('X2').PadLeft(16,'0')
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

For the modulo operation, you can add the divisor until the dividend is greater-than-or-equal-to 0:

```
$i = -1
$d = 256
while($i -lt 0){
    $i += $d
}
$i % 256
```

In most practical application of modular arithmetic, adding the divisor once should suffice:

```
$r = ($i + $d) % $d
```